# ClientWebSocket ConnectAsync always takes slightly longer than 2 seconds

Tags: .net-core, websocket

In a .NET Core 6 console application I'm trying to use the ClientWebSocket class to initiate a connection to a Chrome's DevTools protocol end point but the ConnectAsync(..) call is always taking 2 seconds (and a tiny bit).

In POSTMAN the connection occurs instantly.

Here's the code:

```
var webSocketDebuggerUrl = "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/08F1...D2D2";
using var socket = new ClientWebSocket();
var sw0 = new Stopwatch(); sw0.Start();
await socket.ConnectAsync(webSocketDebuggerUrl, CancellationToken.None);
sw0.Stop(); Console.WriteLine($"connect {sw0.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

The websocket functions perfectly fine, it just takes 2 seconds to connect.

I am completely stumped!

I also can't seem to get any logging whatsoever out of ClientWebSocket().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it myself and timings are exactly the same over 2000ms

Just out of curiosity I checked if there is any difference if I will use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and that was it! `ConnectAsync` execution time dropped to under 50ms

I was trying to find - what might be the reason and I found this issue on chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=272360

Answer there is

> In IPv6 enabled Windows, localhost is resolved as IPv6 address by default. If you don't serve WebSocket at IPv6 localhost, connecting to localhost needs to wait timeout for IPv6 address before taking fallback to IPv4 address, 127.0.0.1.

Hope it helped. I don't know how PostMan works but while I was investigating if maybe some assemblies need to get loaded in runtime, I've copied over your code 2 more times. So application connects and disconects with fresh client. Results were quite interesting because `.net core 3.1`, `.net 6.0`, `.net 7.0` were still showing 2 seconds time on every attempt. But full `.NET Framework` connected first time after 2 seconds but any subsequent attempt took 0ms. What made me think that maybe PostMan is reusing client instance so your requests are already '*aware*' that nothing is listening on IP6 so goes straight to the fallback.

Comment: You sir are gentleman and a scholar! I never even thought that the problem might be outside the .NET code, let alone in the weird world of IPv6 vs IPv4. For my use case I can probably just string replace "http://localhost" with 127.0.0.1. Thank you very much!